# extracting unique currencies into separate columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like:

```
      col
1   €€€€€
2      ££
3      €£
4      €€
5   €€€€€
6    €€€€
7      €€
8      €€
9      €€
10     €€
11     €€
12     €€
13   €€€€
14    €€€
15   €€€€
16     €€
17     €€
18   €€€€
19     $$
20 €€€CHF
```

It contains a collapsed set of currency symbols of different lengths. What I would like to do is to create a new column and extract the unique currencies. In most cases the currencies are all the same however in row 3 and row 20 the currencies look like:  `€£` and `€€€CHF` respectively.

Expected output:

```
      col  colCur1   colCur2
1   €€€€€   €
2      ££   £
3      €£   €          £
4      €€  ...
5   €€€€€
6    €€€€
7      €€
8      €€
9      €€
10     €€
11     €€
12     €€
13   €€€€
14    €€€
15   €€€€
16     €€
17     €€
18   €€€€  ...
19     $$   $
20 €€€CHF   €       CHF
```

Data:

```
    structure(list(col = c("\200\200\200\200\200", "££", "\200£", 
"\200\200", "\200\200\200\200\200", "\200\200\200\200", "\200\200", 
"\200\200", "\200\200", "\200\200", "\200\200", "\200\200", "\200\200\200\200", 
"\200\200\200", "\200\200\200\200", "\200\200", "\200\200", "\200\200\200\200", 
"$$", "\200\200\200CHF")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: How do you know CHF is a currency? Everything seems to be one character, except that and presumably others that are outside of your example set. Do you have a reference list?

Comment: I agree with Adam, identifying distinct currencies is the hard part. If currencies are only a a single symbol or 3 capital letters, I suppose that might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(col2 = str_replace_all(col, "(.)\\1+", "\\1"), 
       col2 = str_replace_all(col2, "([^A-Z])([^A-Z])", "\\1,\\2"),
       col2 = str_replace_all(col2, "(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])", ","), 
       col2 = strsplit(col2, ",")) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(col2)) %>%
    rename_at(-1, ~ str_c('colCur', seq_along(.)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
#   col    colCur1 colCur2
#   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 €€€€€  €       <NA>   
# 2 ££     £       <NA>   
# 3 €£     €       £      
# 4 €€     €       <NA>   
# 5 €€€€€  €       <NA>   
# 6 €€€€   €       <NA>   
# 7 €€     €       <NA>   
# 8 €€     €       <NA>   
# 9 €€     €       <NA>   
#10 €€     €       <NA>   
#11 €€     €       <NA>   
#12 €€     €       <NA>   
#13 €€€€   €       <NA>   
#14 €€€    €       <NA>   
#15 €€€€   €       <NA>   
#16 €€     €       <NA>   
#17 €€     €       <NA>   
#18 €€€€   €       <NA>   
#19 $$     $       <NA>   
#20 €€€CHF €       CHF
```